# Where is my object "dimensions" control?

Tags: interface

Title says it, where is the "Dimensions" control?

I know I'm supposed to be in "Object" mode (I am, see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Hit T button or click on the + icon in the top right corner of 3D view window

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions of your object can be found in the properties panel. To bring up that panel either click on the little '+' icon at the top right of the 3d view or hit <kbd>N</kbd> with your mouse above the 3d view. The dimensions are located under the Transform heading.